# Kafka Stream expose some metrics only

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to expose some Kafka Stream JMX Metrics. But expose and send all of them it will impact the performance of the service.

It is possible expose only some of the metrics of Kafka Stream.

I cannot find a way of doing it, only expose or not the metrics.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It may help to reduce the recording level if the metrics impact the performance of your service. From the documentation:

> By default Kafka Streams has metrics with three recording levels: info, debug, and trace. The debug level records most metrics, while the info level records only some of them. The trace level records all possible metrics. Use the metrics.recording.level configuration option to specify which metrics you want collected